# Reduced, irreducible and integral schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, projective-schemes

I am studying properties of schemes and I have the following problem.

Let $R$ be a ring, $S=Spec(R)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ an integer. Show that the following are equivalent:

1. $S$ is reduced (resp irreducible, resp integral)
2. $\mathbb{A}^n_R$ is reduced (resp irreducible, resp integral)
3. $\mathbb{P}^n_R$ is reduced (resp irreducible, resp integral)

I know that a scheme $S=Spec(R)$ is reduced if and only if nil$(R)=0$;
it is irreducible if and only if nil$(R)$ is prime; and it is integral if and only if it is both reduced and irreducible.

If someone can help me, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Suppose $f=a_ix^i+a_{i+1}x^{i+1}\cdots\in R[x]$ is nilpotent, where $a_i\ne0$. In other words, $f^N=0$ for some $N>0$. Then $a_i^N=0$, contradicting $R$ is reduced. Thus $R$ reduced implies $R[x]$ is reduced. By induction $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is also reduced. Being reduced is a local property so the same statement for $\mathbb P_R^n$ follows.